# Disable Select Option if already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table which clones its last row if all the text boxes are filled and `select` is changed in the previous row. I am trying to add a condition that the newly dropdown options should be disabled if they were already selected in previous rows .

[Demo Fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/18/)

disable option code:

```
$('select').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });

});
```

Full JS:

```
$('#results').append('<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border"> <tr><td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" value="" /> </td> <td> <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1"> <option value="test">test </option><option value="test2">test 2</option></select></td> <td>   <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1" />  </td>   <td> <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="" /> </td></TR></TABLE>'
);
$('select').change(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });

});
    $('#results').on('focus', ':input', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').filter(function() { 
            return !$(this).data('saved'); 
        })
        .find(':input').each(function() {
            $(this).data('value', this.value);
            $(this).closest('tr').data('saved', true);
        });
    })
    .on('input change', ':input', function() {
        $(this).data('filled', this.value != $(this).data('value'))
        var tr  = $(this).closest('tr');
            all = tr.find(':input'),
            fld = all.filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('filled');
            });
        if( all.length == fld.length ) {
            if( !tr.data('done') ) {
                $('#buttonclck')[0].click();
                tr.data('done', true);
            }
        } else {
            if( tr.data('done') ) {

                tr.data('done', false);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#buttonclck').on('click', function () {
        var lastRow = $('#productanddates').closest('#productanddates').find("tr:last-child");
        var lastRowInputs = lastRow.find('input');
        var isClone = false;
        lastRowInputs.each(function() {
           if($(this).val().length) {
               isClone = true;
           }
        });
        if(!isClone)
            return false;
        var cloned = lastRow.clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/;
            var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
            var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

            $(this).attr('id', newId);
            $(this).attr('name', newId);
        });

        cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="results"></div>

<input id="buttonclck" type="button" class="hide"  value="button"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean that if I have selected "test 2" option from the `select` and filled all the inputs, newly generated row should contain `select` without `test 2` option?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr yes you correct the test 2 should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake was here:

```
$(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() { ... }
```

It should be :

```
$(this).children('option').each(function() { ... }
```

Why do you select `siblings` of the `select` element? You should directly descend to its options. I do not know if it is intended, but such code will make `option` disabled in both rows: previous and newly generated.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/19/

Comment: Ma be iam not sure i think you dint update your fiddle it is showing the same

Comment: Hm, that is what i get: http://take.ms/1g6fW Tested in chrome, firefox and edge browsers.

Comment: can you check hear where am i going wrong http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/18/#&togetherjs=f8GBefBhaQ

Comment: sorry to disturb you again that disables only on first select changed on second change the on third row it should not show second rows select but it is showing up http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/26/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/30/, you have to bind `change` event to `select` element once agian, after appending new row.

Comment: the problem seem s to be solved but say i have selected `test1` on first row on second it is disabled but on third row it is enabled ones it is selected it should not enable at all

Comment: Ok, than remove `.siblings().removeAttr('disabled')` from `$(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');`   http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/31/

Comment: Bravo done thanks last and final request is if i enter the values in the text box and then select the option then it doesn't disables the option on second row can you please re check on that

Comment: one more bug if i remove as above suggested then on first select it disables the first option again say i want to change another option that previous selected option is also disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89374/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-pauli).